# Create Out Of Office in MS Outlook Exchange using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

I'm trying to create an Out Of Office (OOO) to communicate dates based on variables.

Base code I'm working with:

```vb
Sub OutOfOffice()
    Const PR_OOF_STATE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661D000B"
    Dim olkIS As Outlook.store, olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    For Each olkIS In Session.stores
        If olkIS.ExchangeStoreType = olPrimaryExchangeMailbox Then
            Set olkPA = olkIS.PropertyAccessor
            olkPA.SetProperty PR_OOF_STATE, True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When I run it, the OOO is not enabled. I read in the web I need to enable Reference "Redemption Outlook and MAPI Library", but I couldn't find it in my Outlook References list.
I found this Redemption library is owned & licensed by Dimastr.com, so it's not part of the Outlook main package.

The final goal is to write an OOO at the moment I create it, with custom text & dates.

As it is an OOO, the PC will be turned off: that's why a macro against received items won't work. Exchange will send OOOs because it triggers from the server. I want to automate it's creation with dates & body, as I would do using "File - Automatic Replies".

Is there a way to achieve this result without depending on external providers?

Comment: You need to declare a `Public Items`  object (`WithEvents`) to trigger `Items_ItemAdd` event of `Inbox` received message. Then automate replay to each received message sender. You can write a piece of code to also Start of Stop OOO messaging sending emails with specific `markers` in the mail Subject or Body.

Comment: @FaneDuru, if I'm understanding correctly, that's more of a workaround than truly using Exchange's OOO capabilities, isn't it? Furthermore, would I need to have the Outlook Application running at all times? If so, it defeats the purpose of an OOO.

Comment: What do you understand by "Outlook OOO Exchange"? Do you want Outlook to trigger the received mail  and reply in a specific way **without being open**?

Comment: Yes, as it is an OOO, the full PC will be turned off: that's why a macro against received items won't work. Exchange will send OOOs because it triggers fromt the Server. I want to automate it's creation with dates & body, as I would do using "File - Automatic Replies".

Comment: Then, try following @Dmitry Streblechenko's suggestion. He is the designer of Redemption. I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set OOF time ranges/ plain text/HTML replies, you need to use EWS and the `UserOofSettings` verb. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/useroofsettings